# GA transaction push uses transaction ID for the product ID

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

As per the title, I have a slightly bizarre issue where I can see in the GA debug console that the transaction ID is being pushed for the products purchased, despite the data layer correctly containing the product ID. So I see the following:

```
ga("gtm6.ecommerce:addTransaction", {id: "100020325", affiliation: "Website", revenue: 38.95, shipping: 3.95, tax: 5.8333})
```

Followed by:

```
ga("gtm6.ecommerce:addItem", {id: "100020325", sku: "80106943", name: "Leather Pouch", category: "Women", price: "35.00", quantity: "1.0000"})
```

However in the data layer, I have:

```
transactionEntity:"ORDER"
transactionId:"100020325"
transactionPayment:"PayPal Express Checkout"
transactionProducts:
Array(1)
0:
category:"Women"
id:"243359"
name:"Leather Pouch"
price:"35.00"
priceexcludingtax:"29.17"
quantity:"1.0000"
sku:"80106943" 
tax:"5.83" 
taxrate:20 
type:"configurable"
```

This is causing transactions not be associated with product list performance due to the IDs not matching (as far as I understand), so all transactions fall under (not set) in GA PLP reports.

Grateful for any help!

Comment: This is the transaction id in both cases. GA uses this to associate the product with the transaction. Products do not have an ID, they have an sku and a name. What do you mean by PLP reports?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to Product List Performance reports. Re products not having an ID, the product ID is documented in the docs. e.g https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases - as I understand it, the transactions aren't currently associated the products with the correct product list, due to the product ID being different in the transaction push

Comment: Products have an id in enhanced e-commerce. AddItem is part of the standard ecommerce. I suspect you are using standard ecommerce code, but have your view set up for EEC.

Comment: @EikePierstorff - you're correct, thanks so much - there was a GTM tag sending a transaction event which seemed to stop the add purchase event from triggering from my code. Disabling the tag fixed the issue